# React - Live Clock Doesn't Work With Initial Value Different Than 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, real-time-clock

I am trying to build a live clock with react for a weather app that will update the time in real time instead of only while refreshing the page.

I managed to update the clock in real time but the problem is that it works only when initial value in useState is set to 0.

Declerations:

```
var today = new Date();
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
```

useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(today.getSeconds());
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [seconds]);
```

This code works **great**, the problem is that since the initial value is 0 - the seconds jump from 0 to 37 for example and only then start updating.

When I try to change the initial value for instance:

```
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(today.getSeconds());
```

The clock starts with the correct second, but doesn't keep updating real time - the clock is stuck.

Any idea?

Comment: If you want to get the current second of time, please use `(new Date()).getSeconds()`, if you do `var today = new Date();` and then `today.getSeconds()`, the value is fixed, so there is no updates.

Comment: If you mean in the useState, then I tried this and still the current second is being displayed but don't update real time.
Updated code:
`const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState((new Date()).getSeconds());`

Comment: `useEffect`, that's the place you update your state.

Comment: I get it now, the solution is so simple I didn't even notice.
Thank you so much!